# Parse Specific Json in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, xml

Im struggling to parse Json for a desired need.

I am extracting Data from a GraphQL call, and need to parse the response and then generate an XML file.

Example JSON Resonse :

```js
{
  "data": {
    "products": {
      "results": [{
        "masterData": {
          "current": {
            "name": "Paragon Pen",
            "description": "TEST",
            "categories": [{
              "name": "Writing Instrument"
            }]
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

I need to parse this and make an xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><product><name>Paragon Pen</name><description>TEST</description><category>Writing Instrument</category></product>
```

I cant get a method to parse and then hold onto the parent element.
For example, i want to make the xml tag  and then add the 'name' element (Writing Instrument) inside this tag. Any help is appreciated.

My Parse method so far.
:

```
    //extractJSON function. Get the information and write it to the file.
function extractJSON(obj) {
    for (const i in obj) {
        if (Array.isArray(obj[i]) || typeof obj[i] === 'object') {
            extractJSON(obj[i]);
        } else {
            if(VERBOSE){console.log(i + ': ' + obj[i]);}

            //Call next step. Write to file.
            eventEmitter.emit('writeToXML',i,obj[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the current output, and your desired output?

Comment: I have a feeling that what is happening is that because you are running the code recursive style, you have a case where you do a "depth-first search". So you wanted parent > child1, child2 but you are getting parent > child1 > child of child1

Comment: But I can't be sure until you tell us what your actual and desired output is

Comment: Hi, The desired out put is the xml from above.

Comment: By which logic is "category" produced in your desired XML when your JavaScript object does not have that (it only has "categories")?

Answer (score 0):

why to parse the entire object?

You should be able to iterate throught the array and emit the events

```
data.products.results.forEach(result, index => eventEmitter.emit('writeToXML',index,result))
```

nevertheless the example xml just support one product, is that correct? so each emit creates its own xml file?

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the name as extra argument to your recursive function.

Here is how you could build the XML string with plain JavaScript:

```js
function encodeXML(s) { // Utility to escape reserved characters in XML data
    const map = { "<": "&lt;", ">": "&gt;", "&": "&amp;", "'": "&apos", '"': "&quot;" };
    return String(s).replace(/[<>&'"]/g, m => map[m]);
}

function extractJSON(name, val) {
    const content = Array.isArray(val) ? val.map( elem => extractJSON("item", elem) ).join``
        : Object(val) === val ? Object.keys(val).map(key => extractJSON(key, val[key]) ).join``
        : encodeXML(val);
    return `<${name}>${content}</${name}>`;
}

// Example:
var obj = {"data":{"products":{"results":[{"masterData":{"current":{"name":"Paragon Pen","description":"TEST","categories":[{"name":"Writing Instrument"}]}}}]}}};

console.log(extractJSON("data", obj.data));
```

Note that for arrays, this does not create numerical child tags ( `<0>`, `<1>` ), but instead a hard-coded `<item>` tags, one for each array element.

If you only need the deeply nested part (like in your desired output), then, just pass a reference to that nested object:

```js
function encodeXML(s) { // Utility to escape reserved characters in XML data
    const map = { "<": "&lt;", ">": "&gt;", "&": "&amp;", "'": "&apos", '"': "&quot;" };
    return String(s).replace(/[<>&'"]/g, m => map[m]);
}

function extractJSON(name, val) {
    const content = Array.isArray(val) ? val.map( elem => extractJSON("item", elem) ).join``
        : Object(val) === val ? Object.keys(val).map(key => extractJSON(key, val[key]) ).join``
        : encodeXML(val);
    return `<${name}>${content}</${name}>`;
}

// Example:
var obj = {"data":{"products":{"results":[{"masterData":{"current":{"name":"Paragon Pen","description":"TEST","categories":[{"name":"Writing Instrument"}]}}}]}}};

console.log(extractJSON("product", obj.data.products.results[0].masterData.current));
```

Note that the `categories` array will be really treated as such, so you still get an `<item>` level in there.